# Need a validation for at least 18 year agers

Tags: android

In My android application i have 2 fields one for dateOfBirth and another for dateOfMarriage. I want to keep the validation that the difference between 2 fields must be > 18years. Can anyone help? Thanks in Advance

Comment: And... What did you tried ? Can you give us a look to your code ? Did you checked on google ?

Comment: Yeah i googled it nothing's working...! I didn't got any exact solution..

Comment: Then you probably need a training course on googling

Comment: I got the solution without googling it...! Anyway thanks for the help for everyone who tried to help me

Answer (score 1):

```
          String dateStart = dob.getText().toString().trim();
          String dateStop =  dom.getText().toString().trim();

               //Date format

          SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

          Date d1 = null;
          Date d2 = null;
          try {
              d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
              d2 = format.parse(dateStop);
          } catch (ParseException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          long diff = d2.getYear() - d1.getYear();
          long year = diff/365;
          if (diff < 19){
              System.err.println("Difference in number of years : " + diff);
              Toast.makeText(DIffdates.this, "DOB & marg should have atleast 18 years gap ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
mycalendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                  int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd",Locale.US);
                Date parse = null;
                Date current =null;
                Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
                int current_year=calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int dates=calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int hours=calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute=calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int months=calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
                int seconds=calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
                String timezone = tz.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT);
                String current_date=(""+current_year+"/"+months+"/"+dates+timezone);
                String month=mycalendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
                String day=mycalendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
                mycalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                mycalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                mycalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                String selected_date=(""+year+"/"+monthOfYear+"/"+dayOfMonth+timezone);
                try {
                    current=sdf.parse(current_date);
                    parse=sdf.parse(selected_date);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                long diff=current_year-year;

                if(diff==18){
                    if(dates>=dayOfMonth){
                        edit_login_date.setText(sdf.format(mycalendar.getTime()));
                        date_of_birth = edit_login_date.getText().toString();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(AddCandidates.this, "Age should be at least 18 years ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
                else if(diff>18){
                    edit_login_date.setText(sdf.format(mycalendar.getTime()));
                    date_of_birth = edit_login_date.getText().toString();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(AddCandidates.this, "Age should be at least 18 years ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Comment: what is edit_login_date, date_of_birth  in the above code?

Comment: here i use date_of_birth as string and edit_login_date is your view where you want to show the date ... use view if required

Comment: I have two edittext fields, when i click on button i have to validate the above condition...!

Comment: compare the values from the calendar on click of the button  set the selected values on the edit text as i done above

Comment: I got the solution ...! Anyway thanks for the help for everyone who tried to help me